# Group processes in the taskbar, is this possible?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm working as a support engineer, and regularly I'm working with several tasks, which imply:

- One or several Windbg sessions
- One or several Visual Studio sessions (application or dumps)

In my taskbar, all Windbg sessions are grouped together, and all Visual Studio sessions are grouped together, and the titles are not always very clear (like `<source file> (Debugging)`, `Source not found (Debugging)` for Visual Studio or `Dump C:\<incomplete_filename>` for Windbg.

I would like to create a group of processes, give it a name, and in there, put all processes, relevant for that one group, e.g.:
I'm working on two memory dumps for ticket `DCP_12345`, and I'll need to open two Windbg sessions (one for every dump) and two Visual Studio sessions (one for a dump, and one for the corresponding application), so I create a group, I call it `DCP_12345`, and after having started the mentioned processes, I add them to that group. Like this, my taskbar does not look like an ununderstandable pile of Windbg sessions, Visual Studio sessions, …, but it consists of different groups, called by the corresponding ticket number, which makes it for me very easy to follow what I'm currently working on.

Is there such a feature in Windows-10? Or a plugin, program, …, to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

**P.s.1** I have tested an applications, called `Bins` (From [1UpIndustries](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/)), it is grouping my processes indeed, but it does not give the opportunity to give a name to the groups.
**P.s.2** I also already experimented with virtual desktops, but I didn't like this a lot (as it's not possible to have a separate background image or any other identifier).

Comment: There's is no such feature in Windows.  How about developing your own solution?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen: thanks for your quick reply. As far as developing my own solution is concerned, this means that I need API requests like: "Get applications, which might be expected in taskbar" (this I might get from `wmic process list` result)", "Clear current taskbar", "add to (item within) taskbar", "get from taskbar", and "remove from (item within) taskbar". Do you know where I might find this in the Windows API? On the other hand, this might prove being quite difficult to develop (but being quite useful), so I wonder if this exists already. If this the right forum for such a question?